# Converting image to grayscale

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, scikit-image, opencv

I want to convert any image to grayscale, but I don't understand the difference between these implementations.

```
image = cv2.imread('lenna.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

gray1 = rgb2gray(image)

gray2 = cv2.imread('lenna.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

image1 = Image.open('lenna.jpg', 'r')
gray3 = image1.convert('L')
```

When I plot them, I get them in blue scale, green scale, green scale and gray respectively. When I should use each one?

Comment: How do you plot them? Also, from which module does `rgb2gray` come from?

Comment: I'm using plt.imshow() and plt.show(). But, even the arrays are different

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've encountered a spot where Python's type system isn't protecting you in the way that C++ would.

`cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` and `cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY` are values from *different* enumerations. The former, whose numerical value is 0, applies to `cv2.imread()`. The latter, whose numerical value is 6, applies to `cv2.cvtColor()`. C++ would have told you that `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` can't be passed to `cv2.cvtColor()`. Python quietly accepts the corresponding int value.

Thus, you *think* you're asking cv2 to convert a color image to gray, but by passing `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE`, `cv2.cvtColor()` sees the value 0, and thinks you're passing `cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA`. Instead of a grayscale image, you get the original image with an alpha channel added.

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

is what you need instead.

The other issue you're seeing, assuming you're using a Jupyter notebook, is that `cv2` layers color planes in BGR order instead of RGB. To display them properly, first do

```
image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

and then display the result.

Comment: But when I use `cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)` shouldn't give the right convertion? Looking at OpenCV's documentation it should works

Comment: Ah, yes. I'm guessing the issue in when displaying. The trick to getting grayscale images to display correctly in notebooks is to do something like `plt.imshow(gray, cmap='gray')`. (That's from memory, so the `cmap` value might be something else. There are lots of options.)

Answer (score 0):

The images that are not gray are the still 3d arrays, that is to say they still somehow retain color information, the reason you are seeing blue and green is because in those 3d arrays the red and green channels in the first case and the blue & red channels in the second have been reduced to 0 leaving only the blue and green that you see.

In order to read the image as grayscale you would use

```
img_gray=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
```

This will yield a 2d array with values between 0 and 255 corresponding to how bright the pixel should be instead of how bright each of the 3 color channels of the pixel should be.

Comment: But what's the difference between them?

Comment: I think the way grayscale works is every pixel is assigned the avg value of the 3 channels, keeping a representation of all three to a certain extent whereas if you only represent one channel you lose the information in the other two